# TF2 account not premium anymore and most items not tradable

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I didn't log into my second steam account for about a year, and today I discovered that I can only trade limited use items, like keys, duels, paints and tags. All other items are marked as non-tradeable, and steam says that I don't have the premium DLC for TF2, though I gifted it to my second account two years ago.

Also, TF2 backpack viewers say the inventory is 300 slots in size, and that those items are not marked non-tradable.

Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Comment: What do you mean "DLC".  DLC has never existed for TF2.

Comment: The signature of owning a premium account is publicly visible as an entry in DLC game menu in steam interface. Like in this pic: http://i.imgur.com/CW0Dz.jpg but with TF2 instead of Dota2.

Comment: Have you enabled SteamGuard? It might be related to that, I think they were planning on disabling trading for accounts that haven't verified with it.

Comment: By "all other items" do you mean weapons and hats? If you bought them from the store or crafted them with untradable metal then they would still be considered untradeable

Answer (score 3):

I've never experienced this specific case myself, but I do have 7 accounts I used for idling in the past (which have since more than paid for themselves). If the account in question has the "[Proof of Purchase](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Proof_of_Purchase)" hat that was given out to people that owned the game before it went Free2Play, you could bring your account to the attention of Valve as that is a dead giveaway that your account *should* be premium. If the account doesn't have that item, then the only other way I know of to get TF2 premium is to buy at least one item in the store (Minimum of $5 in the steam wallet). If what you did was buy/receive the orange box or TF2 back when it was sold and just held onto it until after the game went F2P, it may or may not be a fringe case they haven't handled properly. Regardless, I believe speaking to Valve support directly will be your only solution to this, as they are quite unlikely to allow user action to change premium status short of giving them more money. Best of luck!

Comment: Great first answer. :) Two very minor things: Rather than caps, you should use italics or bold for emphasis. Valve should be capitalised.

Comment: @NightExcessive that's what the edit button is for.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ I figure that giving first posts constructive criticisms helps more.

Comment: @NightExcessive people are alertedwhen their posts are changed, so you could have written that in the comments.